# How to show same control in different pivot item?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Is this possible to show same control in every pivot item.
So I think my options are

1.Change the pivot header but not changing the pivot actually.
2.Add the control as a child control of a grid in another pivot item.[which i think not possible]
3.Just ctrl+c and ctrl+v the design with different names of the control[i don't want to do this].

Is there any other way? Option 1 or option 2 is possible? If yes how?
Please Help.

Comment: Add the control outside of the pivot control?

Comment: other options are - pivot template or custom user control

Comment: Yes, it's possible. In the NaviComputer app have a TextBlock in Pivot that does not scroll. However I don't know how exactly.

Comment: @AMR if i add the control before or after the pivot it is not showing. Have you tried it?

Comment: @seesharp can you explain a bit more

Comment: @souvickcse yes I know exactly what you are asking. I have done this. Its pretty basic if all your talking about is using the same exact instance of a control just outside of a pivot. A pivot is just a control that sits within a grid on a xaml page. Nothing more. You can add controls outside of it. For example I have added a ad banner outside of a pivot control before so the ad appears always across all pivot items and in the same location.

Answer (score 0):

In your case what makes more sense is to create a UserControl.

> I suggest that you create a UserControl from the Grid. It is easy to do in Blend. Open your project in Blend, expand the page contents in the Objects and Timeline panel, right-click on the Grid and select Make into UserControl. Blend will create a UserControl class that you can reuse in each PivotItem.

Taken from [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/9669a098-f8e3-42a8-910a-fa31769d63ee/using-same-pivot-item-with-different-datacountext?forum=wpdevelop)

```
//Now you should be able to do something like this. 
MySecondPivotItem.Content = new MyUserControl()
```

And that's all. Also you can create the PivotItem on the flight and add it to the Pivot, like this: (Assuming that pivotMain is your Pivot)

```
pivotMain.Items.Add(MySecondPivotItem);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: But the problem here is that if i use the same thing for my 2nd pivot item like MySecondPivotItem2.Content = newGrid it will throw exception as it is already added in the view.

Comment: That's why you are creating a new grid, and new control. What you will be doing, is copying the properties that you need from one object to another. Or you can create your own Clone() method, if you need to reuse too many properties.

Comment: But my main requirement is that i will use same control. If i use two object of grid it will be same as two different control.

Comment: Well, first I was kind of confused, but I really can't understand why you will need to have more than one pivotitem with the exactly same control **object** ?? Maybe you don't even need to have a pivot structure.

Comment: I have two pivot item( like "CAR" and "BIKE") and in the view i have almost 40 form fields (they are same for both CAR and BIKE) and they are filters, using those i have to filter db result so the query will be same except where type='CAR' or where type='BIKE'. And the design is pivot item design and i am searching a shortcut :) I can use two button as pivot item header then i have to create the animation view changes all the things. So i am asking is there any other shortest way. And i am very new to wp8.

Comment: Ok, now is more clear what you need. Please check the answer, I edited it.